# How do I spawn items within a radius of a position?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

My code so far is:

```
/summon minecraft:item 6.5 26 -171.5 {Item:{id:"minecraft:gold_ingot",Count:1}}
```

I just don't know how to make them spawn sporadically within a radius.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `spreadplayers` command (which can spread entities as well). You will first need to summon the item somewhere and give it the tag `teleport` which will be used to target it in the next command:

```
summon item x1 y1 z1 {Item:{id:"minecraft:gold_ingot",Count:1},Tags:[teleport]}
```

`x1` and `z1` are coordinates (that don't really matter).

Then, use this command to spread the item somewhere within a given area:

```
spreadplayers x2 z2 spreadDistance maxRange false @e[tag=teleport]
```

`x2` and `z2` are the coordinates of the centre of the area. `spreadDistance` is the minimum distance between items (which only matters if there is more than one item that you're spawning at once). `maxRange` is basically the radius but for a square instead of a circle.

As `spreadplayers` teleports the items to the y-coordinate with a view of the sky, you may need to have a separate command to teleport them to the desired y-coordinate (if the y-coordinate doesn't have a view of the sky):

```
execute as @e[tag=teleport] at @s run tp ~ y ~
```

To make this occur randomly you can link a randomizer (a [dropper one](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tutorials/Randomizers#Dropper_randomizer) ([permalink](https://minecraft.wiki/w/index.php?title=Tutorials/Randomizers&oldid=1392341#Dropper_randomizer)) will probably be sufficient) to a command block with the `summon` command so that the command would activate randomly. Then add a chain command block next to the first command block with the `spreadplayers` command. Add another chain command block with the third `execute` command if it's required.

If you want to spawn multiple items at once, just add more command blocks to the chain (before the `spreadplayers` one) with the same `summon` command.

I haven't tested this but this should work.

---

Note (from [the wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands/spreadplayer) ([permalink](https://minecraft.wiki/w/index.php?title=Commands/spreadplayers&oldid=1411503))):

> The spreadplayers command does not have a uniform distribution over the surface. It has a Gaussian distribution as the positions closer to the position set in the command have a higher chance of having an entity on them. This effect is very subtle and is not visible for short radius but can be a problem if you want a uniform random generation.

Comment: You don't need to `execute at @e` for the teleport command, and if you did you should be using `@s` instead.  Similarly, I would explicitly target an individual entity in the teleport by using `@s`.

Comment: A simpler (but not as good) alternative would be using a dropper very high in the air.

Comment: @MBraedley Without `at @s`, wouldn't it teleport the items relative to the command block and not the items itself?

Comment: Which is why you specify the target to teleport using `@s` like so: `tp @s ~ y ~`.  This is the canonical way to do it, and has been since 1.10 added `teleport` and since 1.13 made `tp` an alias of it.

Comment: In fact, you don't even need the `execute`, you can just use the target selector in the `tp`.

Comment: @MBraedley I tried `execute as @e[tag=teleport] run tp @s ~ y ~` and `tp @e[tag=teleport] ~ y ~`, but it just teleported the items to the x and z coordinates of the command block. According to [the wiki](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Commands/teleport), the `x`, `y`, and `z` arguments "[m]ay use tilde notation to specify a position relative to the position of the executor of the command (use `/execute` to teleport using coordinates relative to the target instead)."

Comment: It's not supposed to do that, but in any case, you can use the `teleport` command instead as that should work as intended.